# How can I know WHICH NAs were introduced by coercion?

Tags: r, validation, na

I have a somewhat messy dataset to clean. Some operations introduce NAs by coercion, but the dataset contains many NAs even without that. How can I determine which rows or elements had NAs introduced.

For example

```
a <- c(1,2,"three", rep(NA, times=10))
as.numeric(a)
 [1]  1  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Results in coercing the third element to a number. Is there a way to identify that it was the third element that caused this, rather than the other NA (non)values? Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, OK, this definitely works for this exact scenario, but I was hoping there might be a more general solution (such as `warnings()`).  In my situation, I've used `read_xlsx()` to generate a tibble, then I need to replace some known problematic strings, which I do with `str_replace()`. That generates the warning `Warning message:
In function_list[[k]](value) : NAs introduced by coercion` so the warning and the function that generates it is obscure. Is there a general way around this or a way to force R to give me the row numbers that generate the warnings? My repro ex. was too simple, I feer

Comment: I can't do that because then I lose that data. I want to read that data in, but then change it so that I can coerce the field to a numeric.

Comment: Thank  you! I think I can make something work with your suggestion. I'm trying to make a new example, but in doing so, my own code works just fine, which is exactly the difficulty -- I don't know exactly what it is in the data that is causing the problems -- so I can't reproduce it. Anyway, I'll use the ideas of your suggestion to help with the sleuthing. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
which(is.na(as.numeric(a)) != is.na(a))
3
# Warning message:
# In which(is.na(as.numeric(a)) != is.na(a)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Also, `which(!is.na(a) & is.na(as.numeric(a)))` although not sure if this is really any different.

Answer (score 0):

Tidy approach, building on markus's solution.

```
library(tidyverse)   
df <- tibble(a = c("1", "2", "three", rep(NA, times=10))) # column `a` in dataframe `df`

df %>%
  filter(is.na(as.numeric(a)) != is.na(a))
```

This returns the rows that would have been coerced to NA's by the as.numeric function.