# Getting the NA's introduced by coercion from a data frame

Tags: r, na, coercion

I have data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("A B C
              1 2 4
              1 1 1
              one 3 5")
```

When converting an entire `data.frame` to numeric, I want to know which `NA`'s were introduced by coercion.

Seeing the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468598/how-can-i-know-which-nas-were-introduced-by-coercion), I tried:

```
which(is.na(as.numeric(dat)) != is.na(dat))
```

But this gives the error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I also tried:

```
for (i in seq_along(dat)) {
  which(is.na(as.numeric(dat[,i])) != is.na(dat[,i]))
}
```

Resulting in:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'i' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..i]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

And finally:

```
for (i in seq_along(dat)) {
    which(is.na(as.numeric(dat[,..i])) != is.na(dat[,..i]))
}
```

For which I again get:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How can I apply this solution to a `data.frame` or `data.table`?

Comment: Similar to the already posted answer but keeps the dimensions of the original object so you can get array indices if desired - `which(is.na(sapply(dat, as.numeric)) != is.na(dat), arr.ind = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
which(is.na(as.numeric(unlist(dat))) != is.na(dat))
```